# Ant build fails after mirrorArchive step

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, p2

So due to having to stick with some eclipse version, I had to install plugins manually by copying them into plugins folder.

After doing that everything works fine and my projects are loaded correctly.

I am using eclipse indigo 3.7.0 64 bit with Xtext 2.9.2

When I run Ant to build my solution it fails at `runDirector` `p2.director` with this message:

```
[java] [p2.director] Missing requirement: Xtext Generator 2.9.2.v201603040440 (org.eclipse.xtext.generator 2.9.2.v201603040440) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator [2.9.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

I don't know much about p2 but I believe that there is some XML file that I should edit or point to some correct repo or something.

I also am getting this in a step before the build fails:

```
[java] [p2.mirror] Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.ui 2.9.2.v201603040440 to bundle org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.ide [2.9.0,3.0.0).
[java] [p2.mirror] Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.xtext.generator 2.9.2.v201603040440 to bundle org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator [2.9.0,3.0.0).
[java] [p2.mirror] Messages while mirroring artifact descriptors.
```

I also tried using `-d` and `-v` when running ant, but this specific part has nothing more than normal in the debug and verbose mode.

Where is `p2.mirror` located?

Where can I set `p2.mirror`?

I am 100% sure that I have these jars, Are they supposed to be somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, I now know what was wrong and I have fixed it. Let me walk you through what I did:

I had to manually install the plugins I need because updating from eclipse itself was impossible because I had to use an old version of eclipse `3.7.0`.

After installing the plugins manually another modification had to be made which was updating the `artifacts.xml` of eclipse manually. Adding entries for missing plugins that are now found in the plugins folder such as:

```
<artifact classifier='osgi.bundle' id='org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator' version='2.9.2.v201603040440'>
  <properties size='1'>
    <property name='download.size' value='1623614'/>
  </properties>
</artifact>
```

After updating the `artifacts.xml`, p2 local repository had to be updated as well because it uses the `artifacts.xml` and needs to see the added list of plugins.

After doing all of this the build worked beautifully. I hope this helps, been stuck for days.

**NOTE: What I had to do is completely discouraged by p2 people, do it at your own risk. See: http://www.slideshare.net/PascalRapicault/dos-and-do-nots-about-p2**